# Declaring function templates before defining when overloading

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, overloading

C++ Primer 5th Edition has a snippet of advice at the end of chapter 16.3 (a chapter discussing function template overloading):

> Declare every function in an overload set before you define any of the
>   functions. That way you don’t have to worry whether the compiler will
>   instantiate a call before it sees the function you intended to call.

So is this telling me that in choosing the candidate and viable functions during overload resolution it is possible the compiler might instantiate a function template that isn't chosen in the end? I tried to see whether this might actually happen:

```
template<class> struct always_false : std::false_type {};

template <typename T> void test(T const &){
    static_assert(always_false<T>::value, "If this fires, it is instantiated");
}

template <typename T> void test(T*) {   }

int main(){
    int *q = nullptr; 
    test(q); //test(T*) should be the best match
}
```

This program would throw a compiler error if `test(T const &)` was instantiated in any form, except the program compiles fine as expected. So what kind of compilation mishap is that tip trying to guard me from? When would it ever instantiate a function before it saw the function I was trying to call?

Comment: Related article on function template specialisation and overloading: [Why Not Specialize Function Templates?](http://gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The author is warning you of this:

```
template<class> struct always_false : std::false_type {};

template <typename T> void test(T const &){
   static_assert(always_false<T>::value, "If this fires, it is instantiated");
}

int main(){
    int *q = nullptr; 
    test(q); //test(T*) will not be matched.
}

template <typename T> void test(T*)
{ 
}
```

And these:

```
template<class> struct always_false : std::false_type {};

template <typename T> void test(T const &){
   static_assert(always_false<T>::value, "If this fires, it is instantiated");
}

template <> void test<int>(int const &);

void test(int *);

int main(){
   int *q = nullptr; 
   test(q); //test(int*) should be the best match
   int a;
   test(a); // test<int>(int const&) should be the best match
}

template <> void test<int>(int const &)
{
}

void test(int *)
{ 
}
```

If you don't provide declarations of

```
template <> void test<int>(int const &);

void test(int *);
```

before `main`, they won't be matched in `main`.

Comment: _before it sees the function you intended to call._ The "before" is what confuses me, in the example you provide `test(T*)` would never have been seen whether `test(T const &)` was there or not. If that's really what the book is suggesting fair enough, but it seems that it's more of a lesson about keeping things in scope than anything to do with templates.

Comment: @AntiElephant, since you already accepted my answer, I am going to assume that you have the answers to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen plenty of SO questions that is some variation of

```
template<class T, class... Ts>
T sum(T t, Ts... ts) { return t + sum(ts...); }
// ^                               |
// |--------------------------------
//    only one visible in 
//     definition context

template<class T>
T sum(T t) { return t; }

int main() {
    sum(1, 2); // doesn't compile
}
```

(The return type isn't perfect, but you get the idea.)

And then people are surprised when it doesn't compile.

Or, even more fun,

```
template<class T> void f(T t) { f((int)t); }
void f(int) { /*...*/ }

int main() { 
    f(1L); // infinite recursion
}
```

Comment: Except when `T sum(T t)` is found by ADL at the point of instantiation (not the case here), which makes it even more funny. E.g., having `struct Foo{ Foo operator+(const Foo&){return *this;}};` at global scope and invoking `sum(Foo{}, Foo{});` inside `main()` will compile.